# exceljs npm package is not working suddenly in node js

Tags: node.js, npm, exceljs, jexceljs

We have implemented xlsx download code in my node js,

We have used exceljs npm package for generate the xlsx file, It was worked as expected in node js 13.x

recently we upgrade the node version to `v16.13.2`

after upgrade the exceljs package is not working, it generated the xlsx but can't open the file

- exceljs version: 4.3.0
- nodejs version: 16.13.2
- npm version: 6.14.14

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue,

Its a version compatability issue

I did the following,

1. Clear the cache

   sudo npm cache clean -f
2. Updated my npm version to 8.12.2

   npm install npm@8.12.2 -g
3. Then install the all package

   npm install

Thats all it solved !!